# Showing the file download progress with NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I want to display file download progress (how many bytes are received) of particular file. It works fine with the NSURLSessionDownloadTask .My question is I want to achieve the same with the NSURLSessionDataTask.

Here is the code which receives file into NSData and writes to document folder:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:theRessourcesURL
    completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{ 
       if(error == nil)
       {

            NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

               NSString *pathToDownloadTo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir, Name];

               NSLog(@"SIZE : %@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);

               [data writeToFile:pathToDownloadTo options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
       }
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

I am getting file size after write or complete datatask (after the file is received) :

`NSLog(@"SIZE : %@",[NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:data.length countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile]);`

But i want to display it's current bytes received status, is this possible with NSURLSessionDataTask?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to implement following delegates:

`<NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate>`

Also need to create two properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *dataToDownload;
@property (nonatomic) float downloadSize;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

    NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: self delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"your url"];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL: url];

    [dataTask resume];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionResponseDisposition disposition))completionHandler {
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);

    progressBar.progress=0.0f;
    _downloadSize=[response expectedContentLength];
    _dataToDownload=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_dataToDownload appendData:data];
    progressBar.progress=[ _dataToDownload length ]/_downloadSize;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for your replay but now problem is this both method not called when i am download file i added delegate and used same above code.

Comment: I have posted another answer please see.

Comment: @KiranPatel i have changed the code plz have a look a tit and let me know if it works. thanks.:)

Comment: WAW! Amazing @ Bullet Raja, Thankyou so much you have solved my problem in minuets i am trying to achieve this since last 2 days. Again thankyou. It works like charm...

Comment: I'm not sure about it. Firstly, they state in the documentation that "As the data may be discontiguous, you should use [NSData enumerateByteRangesUsingBlock:] to access it.". Secondly, it's missing the information how to know the downloading is finished.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use NSURLSessionDownloadTask  like following. Call startDownload methode.In .h file use this

```
- (void)startDownload
{
    NSString *s;
    s = @"http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/1600x1200_autoletterbox/public/pia17474_1.jpg?itok=4fyEwd02";
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]];
    [task resume];
}

- (NSURLSession *) configureSession {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
    [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:@"com.neuburg.matt.ch37backgroundDownload"];
    config.allowsCellularAccess = NO;
    // ... could set config.discretionary here ...
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
    return session;
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
    CGFloat prog = (float)totalBytesWritten/totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    NSLog(@"downloaded %d%%", (int)(100.0*prog));

}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes {
    // unused in this example
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
    UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithData:d];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.image = im;

    });
}

-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"completed; error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Above code working perfectly thanks. But i want to achieve this same functionality with NSURLSessionDataTask instead of NSURLSessionDownloadTask. Does it possible ?

Comment: Sure, No problem please take your time.

Answer (score 5):

Since **iOS 11.0** and macOS 10.13, `URLSessionTask` (former `NSURLSessionTask`) [adopted the ProgressReporting protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000742-TRANSLATED_CHAPTER_965-TRANSLATED_DEST_11). That means you can use the [**`progress`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/2908821-progress) property to track the progress of a session task.

Expecting you already know how to use KVO observers, you can do something like:

```
task = session.downloadTask(with: url)
task.resume()
task.progress.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "fractionCompleted", options: .new, context: &self.progressKVOContext)
```

and observe the value with:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == &self.progressKVOContext, let keyPath = keyPath {
        switch keyPath {
        case "fractionCompleted":
            guard let progress = object as? Progress else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.onDownloadProgress?(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }
        case "isCancelled":
            cancel()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}
```

#### iOS 13 update

`OperationQueue` has now a [`progress` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsoperationqueue/3172535-progress?language=objc).

For example, the `UIProgressView` can observe that property and update the progress value automatically using the [`observedProgress`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiprogressview/1619840-observedprogress). Full example in https://nshipster.com/ios-13/#track-the-progress-of-enqueued-operations.

Comment: Any chance could include Objective-C example?

Answer (score 5):

```swift
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let page = PlaygroundPage.current
page.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let url = URL(string: "https://source.unsplash.com/random/4000x4000")!
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in
  page.finishExecution()
}

// Don't forget to invalidate the observation when you don't need it anymore.
let observation = task.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted) { progress, _ in
  print(progress.fractionCompleted)
}

task.resume()
```