# Progress Bar Download Status Indicator Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, download, progress

I found an example that shows how to do sync & async at [stackoverflow.com here!](http://www.example.com/) This code is just perfect! I want to know how to add Progress Bar for Download Progress for indication. What is the easiest and fastest approach for this? 
I have a table view with some files to download and each cell heigh is more than 200px so it would be nice if i can add a view or subview programmatically and dismiss it when download is finished.

Swift Code posted by [djunod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106868/5094169)

```
import Foundation

class HttpDownloader {

    class func loadFileSync(url: NSURL, completion:(path:String, error:NSError!) -> Void) {
        let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
        let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent!)
        if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(destinationUrl.path!) {
            println("file already exists [\(destinationUrl.path!)]")
            completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:nil)
        } else if let dataFromURL = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
            if dataFromURL.writeToURL(destinationUrl, atomically: true) {
                println("file saved [\(destinationUrl.path!)]")
                completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:nil)
            } else {
                println("error saving file")
                let error = NSError(domain:"Error saving file", code:1001, userInfo:nil)
                completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
            }
        } else {
            let error = NSError(domain:"Error downloading file", code:1002, userInfo:nil)
            completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
        }
    }

    class func loadFileAsync(url: NSURL, completion:(path:String, error:NSError!) -> Void) {
        let documentsUrl =  NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
        let destinationUrl = documentsUrl.URLByAppendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent!)
        if NSFileManager().fileExistsAtPath(destinationUrl.path!) {
            println("file already exists [\(destinationUrl.path!)]")
            completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:nil)
        } else {
            let sessionConfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if (error == nil) {
                    if let response = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                        println("response=\(response)")
                        if response.statusCode == 200 {
                            if data.writeToURL(destinationUrl, atomically: true) {
                                println("file saved [\(destinationUrl.path!)]")
                                completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
                            } else {
                                println("error saving file")
                                let error = NSError(domain:"Error saving file", code:1001, userInfo:nil)
                                completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    println("Failure: \(error.localizedDescription)");
                    completion(path: destinationUrl.path!, error:error)
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

USAGE

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.com/myfile.pdf") 
HttpDownloader.loadFileAsync(url, completion:{(path:String, error:NSError!) in
                println("pdf downloaded to: \(path)")
            })
```

And where should i get that values from 0.0 to 1.0? I understand that i should *divide total size to current downloaded size* but where are that variables?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer provides information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987813/1671729) on how to get progress from a NSURLSession DataTask.

Once you implement those delegate protocols you can get the progress and do whatever you would like with it.  But make sure you do it on the main thread (dispatch_async to the main thread) in order to do your UI updates.